# How do I fix my devtool React user timings?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, performance

I am quite used to using the User timing tab in the devtools console to profile React component updates and how they're affecting the rest of the application where I'm trying to improve performance, e.g.:
[image]

In the app I'm currently working on, these are completely skewed and I can't quite figure out why:

[image]

That is the full view of the entire timeline and as you can see, each of the React timings goes outside of the duration of the profile. It's almost as if their timings were not stopped when necessary.

Struggling to find information on this, thoughts?